Fritzbox router suppressing DNS lookups
PC + Wifi + homeserver
-> router (Fritzbox)
-> UPC cable box
I have 2 NAT after each other.
I have a strange DNS problem. I configured DuckDns to point to an internal IP address.  Resolution works everywhere, but not in the devices connected to the Fritzbox. Here there is a timeout when the DuckDns entry points to an internal IP like 192.168.x.y.
If the Duckdns entry points to a "real" IP, the resolution works correctly.
Then I switched the DNS in the Fritzbox (config menu -> dns server) to 9.9.9.9, however I get the same result. Something does not work as expected, because:
nslookup xx.duckdns.org:  timeout
nslookup xx.duckdns.org 9.9.9.9: can resolve
It seems that the Fritzbox suppresses DNS lookups, when they return an IP which is inside NAT.
Is this plausible?
How can I find out which DNS is really used when Fritzbox is doing the resolution?
Greetings,
exae

It's usually called "DNS rebinding protection", to prevent certain CSRF attacks under the same name.

https://en.avm.de/service/knowledge-base/dok/FRITZ-Box-7590/3565_FRITZ-Box-reports-Your-FRITZ-Box-s-DNS-rebind-protection-rejected-your-query-for-reasons-of-security/

